# XCode Product Archive creates empty archive file

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, archive

When I try to create an archive for distribution in XCode 4.2 by clicking Product -> Archive, the build seems to succeed but the resulting archive file ([APPNAME] [BUILDDATE] [BUILDTIME].xcarchive) is empty, size shows 0 byte.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?